# androidx-main: unable to find remote helper for 'sso'

Tags: android, repo

I want to build and run the androidx lib, following this [manual](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main/docs/onboarding.md) but when downloading the code encounter this:

```
$ repo init -u sso://android/platform/manifest \
>     -b androidx-main --partial-clone --clone-filter=blob:limit=10M

manifests:
fatal: unable to find remote helper for 'sso'
manifests: sleeping 4.0 seconds before retrying

manifests:
fatal: unable to find remote helper for 'sso'
fatal: cannot obtain manifest sso://android/platform/manifest
```

I've already [Set up access control](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main/docs/onboarding.md#access), got the `.gitcookies` file and

```
$ git config --list
user.name=<hide this>
user.email=<hide this>
color.ui=auto
http.proxy=127.0.0.1:7890
http.cookiefile=/home/<hide this>/.gitcookies
https.proxy=127.0.0.1:7890
core.autocrlf=input
credential.helper=store
```

And at adnroid-review.googlesource.com:

```
New Contributor Agreement
Select an agreement type:
 Google CLA
Agreement already submitted.
Google Contributor License Agreement
```

Did I miss some thing?